# Prove that if $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_k$ are distinct subgroups of order $p$ then $|H_1\cup H_2\cup\dots\cup H_k| = 1+k(p-1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $p$ be a prime,but I fail to see how.

Prove that if $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_k$ are distinct subgroups of order $p$ then $|H_1\cup H_2\cup\dots\cup H_k| = 1-k(p-1)$.

This is easy to see in the case $p=2$ and $k=3$. Although I am not seeing how I can prove it. I can't use induction as $p$ is prime.

So I believe the proof will follow from the following facts.

I know that each $H_i$ is cyclic. And also that if $H=\langle h \rangle$ then $|H|=o(h)$.

I also proved that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of order $p$ then $H=K$ or $H\cap K=\{1\}$.

Any hints or suggestions that my light my way?

Comment: It should actually be $1+k(p-1)$. I'll correct it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: It follows immediately from the fact that if $H$ and $K$ are distinct subgroups of order $p$, then $H\cap K=\{1\}$. For $i=1,\ldots,k$ let $A_i=H_i\setminus\{1\}$. The sets $A_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ are pairwise disjoint, so ... ?